# What is "hobby Ml"?

Tags: word-meaning

Sentence:
With Mount Rainier keeping a constant vigil over the city, it's no wonder many Seattleites claim mountaineering as hobby Ml.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is based on a character-rendering glitch on a web page.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't mean anything.  I see that sentence copied a bunch of times on different websites.  The original says, "..many Seattleites claim mountaineering as hobby №1."  Apparently not all websites can correctly render the "№" character, and are turning it into "M" (and the "1" into "I")